# how to look for multiple values of objects in an array sum two property values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects where I need to look at two properties to arrive at a value.

```
let limit =  [
    {
        NodeId: "9837f279",
        NodeName: "Node1",
        summary: {
            current: 50,
            limit: 75
        }
    }, {
        NodeId: "4189f279",
        NodeName: "Node2",
        summary: {
            current: 60,
            limit: 100
        }
    }, {
        NodeId: "9837f279",
        NodeName: "Node1",
        summary: {
            current: 30,
            limit: 75
        }
    }
]
```

Here I need to add all nodes:

```
summary.current / summary.limit = (50 + 60 + 30) / (75 + 100 + 75)
```

How can I do this using JavaScript?

Comment: The usual practice here is that you research ways to iterate your array, attempt some code, post what code you tried and explain where you got stuck.  We are not meant to be a programming service that just writes code for you without you attempting to first solve your own problem.  We are meant to be problem solvers to help you solve problems with the code you  have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest familiaring yourself with [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
const totalCurrent = limit.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.summary.current, 0);
const totalLimit = limit.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.summary.limit, 0);

const totalUtilisation = totalCurrent / totalLimit;
```